# mongoid immutable record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am building a Rails 3.2 application and I have to encapsulate Sidekiq jobs in a seperate model just to maintain relationships and handle insertions and deletions.

I am using Mongoid as my primary ORM and I would like to ask how I can make immutable records.

This means that after (intialization and) creation of job, no changes would be acceptable but deleting the record.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Rails app is the only MongoDB client, you can implement your immutability logic at the model layer:

```
class Job
    include Mongoid::Document
    before_validation { false if changed? && persisted? }
end
```

The first time you call `save` or `create` on a new `Job`, the data will persist successfully. Further changes to the object will not be written to the database when you call `save`. The behavior of `delete` will be unaffected.

**Why this works**

`before_validation` cancels persistence if false is returned:

> If the returning value of a before_validation callback can be evaluated to false, the process will be aborted and Base#save will return false. If ActiveRecord::Validations#save! is called it will raise a ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exception. Nothing will be appended to the errors object.

**Method Reference**

1. [changed?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed-3F) returns true if any fields are dirty
2. [persisted?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F) returns true if some version of this object is saved in the database

Answer (score 1):

I expanded on Sebastian's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14354233/551557) to make the behaviour clearer.

```
class Job
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :msg, type: String

  validate :immutability

  def immutability
    if changed? && persisted?
      errors[:base] << "#{self.class.name} is immutable and cannot be modified after it has been persisted"
    end
  end
end
```

This is how it works:

```
> job = Job.create(msg: 'Hello')
=> #<Job _id: 55a7ccb76d61634e87000000, msg: "Hello">
> job.update_attributes!(msg: 'Goodbye')
Mongoid::Errors::Validations:
Problem:
  Validation of Job failed.
Summary:
  The following errors were found: Job is immutable and cannot be modified after it has been persisted
Resolution:
  Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.
        from /...
> job.destroy!
=> true
```

This has 2 main benefits:

1. The error message is much more explanatory than what you get with `before_validation` (`Calling update_attributes! on Job resulted in a false return from a callback.`)
2. It follows Mongoid recommendations on [not using callbacks for domain logic](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html#callbacks): *Using callbacks for domain logic is a bad design practice, and can lead to unexpected errors that are hard to debug when callbacks in the chain halt execution. It is our recommendation to only use them for cross-cutting concerns, like queueing up background jobs.*